# For some reason odd reason i can't seem to make my code write in the txt file

Tags: python, file, module

So i have written this code where i want the computer to open a file and write in it what the user have answered to the question i asked him but when ever i open the txt file its empty.

```
import os 

Welcome = input("Hi my name is Steve. Do you have an account at Steve? ANSWER WITH JUST A YES OR NO ")

def register():
    name = input("First name: ")
    last_name = input("Last name: ")
    Email = input("Email: ")
    ussername = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
def login():
    ussername = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

if Welcome == "yes":
    login()
else: 
    register()

if Welcome == "no" or "No":
    with open("userinfo.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(register())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing anything to the file. I have modified the code to add the response to the file and also changed the code to be more accurate.

```
welcome = input("Hi my name is Steve. Do you have an account at Steve? ANSWER WITH JUST A YES OR NO ")


def register():
    first_name = input("First name: ")
    last_name = input("Last name: ")
    email = input("Email: ")
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    with open("userinfo.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(f"{first_name}\n{last_name}\n{email}\n{username}\n{password}")


def login():
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")


if welcome.upper() == "YES":
    login()
    print("LOGGED IN!")
elif welcome.upper() == "NO":
    register()
    print("REGISTRATION SUCCESFULL!")
else:
    print("WRONG INPUT!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is empty because you're not writing anything into it. Your `register()` function does not return anything, so nothing gets written into the file.

Maybe you want to add something like

```
return f"{name} {last_name}"
```

to the end of your `register()` func? At least then something should get written to your output file.

Also, you have a logic error in `if Welcome == "no" or "No":`

I would change that to:

```
if Welcome.lower() == "no":
```

That fixes your logic error.

The line you wrote could have been written as:

```
if Welcome == "no" or Welcome == "No":
```